# I want to Get a Bar chart when clicking on a tab or something in a pie chart made by using plotly and rshiny package

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

-

Need help... I had created a pie graph comparing count of car makes of US industry and Autongin(internal purpose). Also I had created a bar chart comparing Car Model counts of each car makes in US industry and Autongin.I want to get this bar chart  when clicking on a tab  or something displayed in the pie chart window .I created the graph using plotly package and the database is connected .I want to get the bar chart created when clicking on tab displayed in pie chart window.

The sample dataset used to plot pie chart is attached here

```
 AutonginMake    USMakename
1   Acura           Acura
2   Aston Martin    Aston Martin
3   Audi            Audi
4   Bentley         Bentley
5   BMW             BMW
6   Buick           Buick
7   Cadillac        Cadillac
8   Chevrolet       Chevrolet
9   Chrysler        Chrysler
10  Dodge           Dodge
11  Ford            Ford
12  GMC             GMC
13  Honda           Honda
14  HUMMER          Hummer



#packages needed
    library(plotly)
    library(shiny)
    library(DBI)
    library(RMySQL)
    #connecting db
    dealerinventory1<-dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user='ghhjjl', 
                                password='dfgfdgdg!', 
                                host='hfghfh', 
                                dbname='hhthhq23u')
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(tagList(
  plotlyOutput("pie"),

  verbatimTextOutput("makes")
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  uscount1=dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                     'SELECT count(distinct makename) as USmakes FROM dealer_inventory.CarQuery;')

  autongincount1=dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                            'SELECT count(distinct makename) as autonginmakes FROM dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup;')


  usandautongintable <- c(autongincount1,uscount1)
  usandautongintable
  label <- c(paste("Autongin Count: ", autongincount1),paste("US Industry Count: ", uscount1))
  label

  unlist <- as.numeric(unlist(usandautongintable))

  typeof(unlist)

  table<- as.data.frame(usandautongintable)
  table
  usmakes <-    dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,"SELECT distinct makename as USmakes FROM dealer_inventory.CarQuery;")
  autonginmakes <- dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                              'SELECT distinct makename as autonginmakes FROM dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup;')
  usmakes_count <- dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                              'SELECT count(distinct makename) as USmakes FROM dealer_inventory.CarQuery;')
  autonginmakes_count <- dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                                    'SELECT count(distinct makename) as autonginmakes FROM dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup;')

  output$pie <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(table, labels = label,
            values = unlist,
            key=c("us", "autongin"),
            type = "pie")  %>%
      layout(title = 'Comparison of Makes',
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
  })



  output$makes <- renderPrint({
    clicked <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(clicked)) {
      "Click on US Industry Count or Autongin"
    } else if (clicked$key == "us") {
      autonginmakes
    } else {
      usmakes
    } 
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output plot link is here http://autonginreports.iinerds.com:3838/sample-apps/plot/

The above code is used to create pie chart .

The code following is used to create bar plot

```
param_modelyear=c(2008:2018)
for ( i in param_modelyear){ 
  print(i)
  }


modelyearquery=paste0(" (SELECT A.makename as AutonginMake,Case when B.makename is null Then A.makename
                      Else B.makename end As USMakename
                      ,A.AutonginModelcount,Case when B.USModelcount is null Then 0
                      Else B.USModelcount end as USModelcount
                      FROM (select count(*) as AutonginModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as C
                      group by makename) A Left JOIN (select count(*) as USModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.CarQuery where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as D
                      group by makename) B ON A.makename=B.makename
                      ORDER BY A.makename)
                      UNION
                      (SELECT  Case when A.makename is null Then B.makename
                      Else A.makename end As AutonginMake,B.makename as USMakename,Case when A.AutonginModelcount is null Then 0
                      Else A.AutonginModelcount end as AutonginModelcount,B.USModelcount
                      FROM (select count(*) as AutonginModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as C
                      group by makename) A Right JOIN (select count(*) as USModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.CarQuery where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as D
                      group by makename) B ON A.makename=B.makename
                      ORDER BY A.makename);")
modelyearquery
makemodel1=dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,modelyearquery) 
plot5 <- plot_ly(makemodel1, x = ~AutonginMake, y = ~USModelcount, type = 'bar', name = 'USModelcount') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~AutonginModelcount, name = 'AutonginModelcount') %>%
  layout(
    title="Yearwise comparison of Models of each Makes in Autongin and US market",
    yaxis = list(title = 'modelcount'), 
    barmode = 'group')
plot5   
library(shiny)
library(plotly)


models= fluidPage(selectInput('my_dropdown','Choose Column',param_modelyear),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)


server3<- function(input,output){
  output$plot=renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(makemodel1, x = ~AutonginMake, y = ~USModelcount, type = 'bar', name = 'USModelcount') %>%
      add_trace(y = ~AutonginModelcount, name = 'AutonginModelcount') %>%
      layout(
        title="Yearwise comparison of Models of each Makes in Autongin and US market",
        yaxis = list(title = 'modelcount'), 
        barmode = 'group')
  })
}

shinyApp(models,server3)
```

I want to get the bar chart "plot5" when clicking on tab or something displayed on pie chart window

```
plot5 <- plot_ly(makemodel1, x = ~AutonginMake, y = ~USModelcount, type = 'bar', name = 'USModelcount') %>%
      add_trace(y = ~AutonginModelcount, name = 'AutonginModelcount') %>%
      layout(
        title="Yearwise comparison of Models of each Makes in Autongin and US market",
        yaxis = list(title = 'modelcount'), 
        barmode = 'group')
```